# Moto G6 audio sending through wrong audio channel

Tags: audio, motorola-moto-g, bugs

My unrooted, basically stock android decided to stop sending audio through any channels except call audio today. I have not installed any new or unstable apps recently. Symptoms include:

1. the lower speakers (the ones used for playing music, etc.) are completely nonfunctional.
2. The upper speaker sounds like I'm in a call all the time. When I am actually in a call, it is nearly silent unless I'm on speakerphone, at which point it's as quiet as any other app.

I have attempted general troubleshooting. To wit, this includes:

1. I closed all current apps and then tested sound. No change.
2. I rebooted the device. No change.
3. I booted into 'Safe Mode.' Problem persisted.
4. Connection over Bluetooth seems to be immune to the issue. I connected a headset and nearly blew out my right eardrum.

Any suggestions on what the heck is going on and/or how to fix it?

Update:

Appears it was a hardware issue, as it spontaneously corrected itself a few days later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, I waited for a few days and it fixed itself in the middle of the night. I don't know why. Sorry, future humans!

Given that it both spontaneously started and stopped, that it persisted through multiple restarts, and that it was present during safe mode, I suspect that this was either a hardware issue or it was embedded in the registry.

*note to editors: this answer is here simply to successfully close the question.*